# Telegram bot send private message to a specific person

Tags: java, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

i built by using java
a telegram bot
which basically get users's name
it can be 1 or 10 or even 40 (i limited it to 50) depends on how much you want to put
now the purpose of this bot is later on when you finish with your specific users
you write a message to send them

now everything is work perfect the id names getting save as well the message
although
how do i send it to all the users i just insert as a private message
if it even possible... by command

i hope i was understandable enough

thats my code:

```
    class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

public int counter = 0;
public ArrayList names = new ArrayList(50);
public SendMessage mainMessage = new SendMessage();
public String sgMsg = "";
public StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

public String msg;
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    String command = update.getMessage().getText();
    SendMessage sysMsg = new SendMessage();
    sysMsg.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());



    String firstCdletter;
    firstCdletter = Character.toString(command.charAt(0));


    if (command.equals("/start")) {
        sysMsg.setText("Enter the user's id, to finish send: Ok");
        try {
            execute(sysMsg);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counter = 0;
        names.clear();
        sgMsg = "";
    }else if (firstCdletter.equals("@")) {

        String user = command;
        names.add(counter);
        counter++;

    }else if(command.equals("/ok")){
        sysMsg.setText("Good, now write your message you want to deliver");
        try {
            execute(sysMsg);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }else if(command.equals("/done")){
        msg = stringBuilder.toString();
    }else{
        sgMsg = update.getMessage().getText();
        stringBuilder.append(sgMsg + " ");
    }

}
```

thank you all for your time and help

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you **cannot** send message via `@username`, the only identify you can use is UID (looks like `109780439`).

And by the way, bot have to chat with that user before, or you will got an [400 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940269/5201431).

Comment: alright so lets say all those people get that bot lets say 20 people
but i want that only 4 people will get the same message 
so i need to use their UID ?
and if so where do i get that UID ?

Comment: You can let users forward message from that user

Comment: alright so how do i get their User id 
or atleast convert their username into User id
so i could send them the message

Comment: @Sean can't we integrate Telegram like whatsapp? There are number of sites that sends message to users on whatsapp? Like OYO does, when user book a room then OYO sends details on user's whatsapp. How to do it using Telegram?